# How do I set the year on Galaxy Tab beyond 2036?

Tags: samsung

I want to set the year on my Galaxy Tab beyond the Year 2036 but it doesn't let me.

Is there a workaround, which would allow me to do that?

Seems odd, there there would be a date limit, but I guess there is!

Question is, how do I circumvent it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [Possible explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: Yes but I dont even get to year 2038, im stuck in 2036!